# In which case we have to use one of these Object literal, constructor function and Object.create() and how they are differ from one another?

Tags: javascript, object

We can create the object in JavaScript through three ways :-

1.) var obj = {name:'John', age:30, gender:'male'};//using object literal

2.) var a = new Test();// using constructor function

3.) var obj = Object.create(null);// using Object.create() method

But my question is, when we have to use object literal, constructor function and Object.create() method. And also the difference between these three.
Like in which case or which kind of requirement we can use one of these according to that requirement.
And give me some real project example.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic and clearest way to make an object is with the object literal syntax. 
However that is not always practical, say if you want to make many objects with the same property keys just with different values, it is a lot quicker and less verbose to use the constructor function.

And regarding Object.create(), the main usage for that is to inherit the prototype of another object and not made to create its own values (even though it is possible.)